# Capturing, saving and displaying pictures in activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, start-activity

I have 3 buttons and a toggle in my activity. When toggled, the buttons should open the camera to capture an image or prompt to select one from gallery and 'save' it. When not-toggled, the buttons should display the image it was used to take in a main ImageView.

Three buttons:

```
//buttons 1,2,3 are the same
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(toggled == true){
            takePictureIntent();
        }
        else {
            //display the picture
        }
    }
});
```

My camera/gallery code is from a tutorial/forum online:

```
private void takePictureIntent() {
final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
    final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    cameraIntents.add(intent);
}
// Filesystem.
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Chooser of filesystem options.
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
// Add the camera options.
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
//}
```

}

Can somebody please guide me towards how to have the button "remember" the picture taken through it so that, when the toggle is off, it will display it?

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, any help is appreciated.